# Is there any library that gives access to PC (windows) microphone in a way Open CV gives access to camera?

Tags: c++, c, windows, capture, microphone

So in Open CV we have such easy [way](http://opencv.willowgarage.cobm/wiki/CameraCapture) of getting to some camera device and its data:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// A Simple Camera Capture Framework
int main() {

  CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
  if( !capture ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }

  // Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
  cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
  while( 1 ) {
    // Get one frame
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    if( !frame ) {
      fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
      getchar();
      break;
    }

    cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
    // Do not release the frame!

    //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
    //remove higher bits using AND operator
    if( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
  }

  // Release the capture device housekeeping
  cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
  cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any such audio library or OpenCV extention that would provide alike way of dealing with mic and samples from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same API that OpenCV uses.  You need the waveInXxxx() functions for recording audio.  A good example is [available here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SoundRecord.aspx).